# Is there an open-source Selenium Webdriver Test Automation Framework that's already available in the market?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework

I've been practicing Web Automation for a year now. This may sound funny , but, is there a Test Automation Framework
for Selenium Webdriver? (Java binding). Like, when you set up the framework, it already provides you
with the necessary files like, POM files, Object Repository, Reporting and even Excel files for your data and all you need is a bit of manipulation and customization ?

I think I have created my own mini-framework through learning online lessons (using POM approach, Excel for my test data, Object Repository files and so on) but I'm not so confident about it's robustness and reusability. Also, it takes time to build and it requires some sort of deep understanding on OOPs. Somehow, I wonder if there's just Selenium Webdriver framework (that uses Selenium WebDRIVER APIs/Libraries)that I can use and setup immediately and everything would be ready on the go? OR Maybe there's other Test Automation Framework that satisfies my conditions above? Thanks guys. I would gladly hear about your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This is a very subjective question. What you are actually looking for is a test harness. There are n number of libraries out in the market for the components you are looking for, e.g

1. Logging - Apache Log4j
2. Framework - TestNG
3. Test Pattern - Page Object Pattern, Loadable Components, Page Factory and so on.
4. Excel
   read/write - Apache POI
5. Reporting - ReportNG, ExtentReport, Allure

Your so called test framework will completely depend on the kind and nature of application you are automating. 
I would suggest go thru a programming language in detail and how you can bind all these component together.

There are a lot of open source projects on selenium which you can go thru. Have a look at the below link for creating simple Page Objects.

https://github.com/RationaleEmotions/SimpleSe

Mozilla also has a lot of test suites open sourced.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called Stevia, haven't used personally, though:

https://github.com/persado/stevia